# Bootstrap 4 - How to Define Min Quantity Cards in Row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Boostrap 4, how can I set a minimum number of cards per line?

I have Bootstrap 4, HTML5, CSS and jQuery.

These cards will be added dynamically, so it will also need to be responsive.

**Incorrect:**

```
1 | 2 | 3

4 | 5 | 6
```

**Correct:**

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 

6
```

**Here's my attempt:**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...... 
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@media (min-width: 512px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}
//..... 
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: card-columns don't order left to right, they order top-to-bottom. Did you try using the grid instead? The actual question isn't clear. Are you saying you want a minimum of 5 on all screen widths?

Comment: I not using grid instead, because cards are added dynamically. I would need the cards to be horizontally aligned, left to right.  The total amount of cards should vary across screens, but the minimum i should be ( column count)

Comment: *"I not using grid instead, because cards are added dynamically"* what does using the grid have to do with the cards being added dynamically? The only way to order left-to-right is to used the grid.

Comment: Gabriel you don't seem to understand BS4 behavior. Read the documentation again.

- You code is broken because only <div class="row"> can be children of .container

- If you generate layout automaticaly : place your cards in a <div class="col-auto">  so the column will take the space it requires

- Or for cards that have the same size, just wrap your card in a <div class="col">. These will go to the next line when line is full (thanks to flex-wrap).
If you want these cards to be stacked on small devices and aligned on large, use col-sm instead of col